Compatibility of power supply
I have an eight-terabyte backup disk that got separated from its power adapter during a house move.  The drive's label says it needs 12V, 3.0A.  I do have an adapter that is labeled 12V, 3.0A.  The connector is also compatible with the socket.
Is there any factor other than voltage, current capacity, and connector design that might make it a bad idea to try to use this adapter?

It might even be the adapter that came with the drive.  But the correct adapter might be in some other box not yet unpacked.  I've gone more than a few days without backups, so I need to stop hoping one labeled "Seagate" will show up.

Check the polarity. If the power supply is positive voltage on the center connector terminal but the hard drive expects negative voltage, you may destroy the drive.

@DoxyLover, good point!  Unfortunately, finding my meter has the same problem as finding any other adapters.  Also, if I find the meter, I can check the adapter, but I can't tell which polarity the drive needs.  More than half of the stuff the movers delivered from the other house is still boxed in the garage.  On the plus side, I have three other backup disks that are powered by their interface cables.

@WGroleau You can look for the manual on the drive and hope they specify the polarity. It's possible and worth a shot before risking destruction. Quite unlikely, but a very remote possibly, would be the adapter supplies 12 vac. Just mentioning it to dot i's and cross t's. In no way do I believe it's true.

You can measure which terminal is likely ground by knowing which USB terminal ia ground and using that for comparison. There is no need to open the case Assuming the drive takes in DC to begin with.

This has already been closed as off-topic as a usage question, but I would personally have just marked it as a duplicate of the canonical power supply ratings question, the answers to which I believe will answer any questions you have.

@Hearth, the answers there tell me things I already knew and implied in my question text.  My question was whether there were other factors to consider.  And the answer already given here and not there is "Yes—polarity and whether AC or DC."

The safest thing to do, is to open the case and trace from the (presumably two) input connector positions (typically a socket and pin) to
the GND (typically black wire) and +12 (typically yellow wire)that
feed the hard disk mechanism.   If a multimeter indicates low resistance,
that's the best test.   It's also possible to seek the highest
voltage electrolytic capacitor(for a hard disk, that's usually a 16 or 25V capacitor) which would undoubtedly be the +12V input filter; its
positive terminal should trace to the ON/OFF switch and the +12V
contact on the adapter.
If the data is critical, one could also substitute a 'test dummy' known
good hard drive to see if it is recognized before risking the original.
Things used to be worse; it was once common for +12 +5, ground, and shield
connections to be applied to a three-to-six pin connector; it takes a lot
of checking to map the pinouts of one of those.
One possible problem: some designs 'protect' the input by using a fuse or
a Zener diode, and those designs aren't always wisely sized.   The +12V motor power isn't critical (plus or minus two volts is probably just fine)
unless the engineering was done creatively and blows fuses.

Seagate's website no longer shows this model number.  If I were able to get another "test dummy" (hundred dollars plus), I'd just use the adapter that comes with it on this one.  Opening the case to look is a viable option.  And it seems folks have decided this question is not about electronics.

Other seagate drives put positive on the center hole.  yes, it's off topic here... ask in superuser.
